# Finding which commits are new on a fork

Tags: git, github

Given a fork of a repository, how can I find which commits have been made on this fork that do not exist in the original repository? It seems that there is no such feature in the GitHub API nor on the website itself, from what I can find.

The reason why I want this is because I want to find interesting forks for a popular repository that have developed new features, which have not been merged into the original respository. There are over 6000, and while I have narrowed the forks down somewhat, it's difficult to see which commits are actually part of the new features.

Any help?

Comment: `git rebase master` should trim identical git commit...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how to [compare git commits across forks](https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/) , if you're interested you can do it from github directly like this:

```
https://github.com/<user1>/<repo>/compare/<branch>...<user2>:<branch>
```

note that the `...` is part of the url

Comment: I don't think this works if the fork has been fast-forwarded, which most of the forks have that I'm looking at.